# Can binary sequences generated from ergodic maps be chaotic?

Tags: mathematical-physics, probability, statistics, chaos-theory, ergodicity

Briefly, the way symbols are generated is:

Consider a one-dimensional chaotic map $T: [0,1]→[0,1]$ and a time series $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N$ generated with this map. Define a threshold $A$ and a thresholding function $π$:

$$\pi(x) := \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if} \quad x>A \\
  0  & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Consider a symbolic sequence $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^N$ obtained by applying $π$ to the elements of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N$, i.e., $s_i := π(x_i)$

For example, let $A =0.5$ be the threshold and the time series $x = [0.1,\, 0.56,\, 0.6,\, ...]$. Then

$\pi(x_1) =  0$;

$\pi(x_1) =  1$;

$\pi(x_2) =  1$.

Thus, the symbolic representation is $s = [0,1,1]$

I am facing technical difficulties in following the paper. My question is: Such binary sequences are just *i.i.d.* random variables of some distribution. How can we say that these sequences $s$ are chaotic?

Comment: This is more of a math question. I don't think this differs fundamentally from any other pseudo-random generation schemes (most of which are probably based on chaotic maps even though that word wasn't in use when they were invented). In general, though, the quality of a pseudo-random number generator always has to be tested based on the relevant criteria, starting with a chaotic system is absolutely no guarantee for pseudo-randomness.

Comment: *So, a map $\pi: X \rightarrow \Sigma_2$.* – I fail to understand this: You are mapping from a single sequence to the set of all sequences? Why? What is the connection to the rest of the question?

Comment: I am mapping each real number $x \in X$ to its corresponding symbol from $\Sigma_2 = {0,1}$ depending on which partition $x$ falls within. The resulting symbolic orbit is called the symbolic dynamics of the real orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When such 0/1 sequences are generated, they are just i.i.d random variables of some distribution.

No, they aren’t.

As for ***identically distributed***, consider any sequence when changing $A$. The higher $A$, the higher the probability that the symbol is $1$.

As for ***independently***, consider the sequence generated by a tent map and then transform all values via
$$f(x) := \left(x-\tfrac{1}{5}\right) \bmod 1.$$

The corresponding sequence could as well have been generated by a somewhat shifted tent map, which looks like this:

[image: shifted tent map]

If you select $A=\tfrac{7}{10}$ (see plot), it should become obvious that the probability that a $1$ is followed by another $1$ is higher than the probability that that a $0$ is followed by a $1$, so the symbol sequence has some memory.

---

> How can we say that these sequences S are **chaotic**?

It all boils down to your definition of chaoticity at the end, but consider the following: Let $T$ be the classical tent map (forget the above shift) and let $A:=\tfrac{1}{2}$. Now, if we represent numbers in binary, the effect of the map on a number can be understood as removing its first digit after the decimal point, e.g., $$T(0.10100101011101) = 0.0100101011101,$$ $$T(0.0100101011101) = 0.100101011101,$$ and so on. Due to our threshold selection, we also have that $s_i$ is the digit removed from $x_i$ by $T$. Thus your sequence $s$ is the sequence of digits of $x_0$.

Thus, the more precisely, we know $x_0$, the longer can we accurately predict the sequence $s$, but any finite precision will make it impossible for us to predict $s$ forever. This is very reminiscent of the Butterfly Effect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply with the graphs. Somethings are still unclear: The paper that I linked to and many others mention that the sequences are iid random variables. Hence, they are used as pseudo random number generators. I am not sure why you say they are not.

Comment: Next, the shift map is said to be chaotic according to literature but are the symbols so generated chaotic? What I mean is if the iterates generated from an initial condition $x_0$ Is chaotic, then for next iterate $x_1$, the binary representation of rational number $x_1 = 0.6$ (say) would be chaotic as well? In essence, by symbolic dynamics do we mean converting real number to its binary? Is the output $0.01001010...$ chaotic?

Comment: Then, I think the shift is to the left of the decimal point and dropping off the symbol, thus shifting to the left. So, $T(0.101) = 1.01 =, T(1.01) = 0.1..$ Lastly, is there a way to model/ represent the symbolic representation by an equation? Literature says that A Bernoulli Map acts as the Shift Map. So, can we say that Bernoulli Map is used to represent the symbolic dynamics? Thank you for your valuable insights and effort.

Comment: @SKM: As I said, it depends on your definition of chaos, which usually does not apply to time series, in particular chaotic ones (i.e., they are neither chaotic nor not chaotic). The output 001001… bears no sign of chaoticity, but neither does the unsymbolised sequence generated by the tent map if $x_1=0.6$. But for any real $x_0$, there will be no repeating pattern. Note that I do not use the shifted tent map in the last part; that’s a regular tent map.

Comment: Based on your answer which is logical that the 001001..are not chaotic, then why do the papers and those cited inside say that Chaotic (Binary) Sequences? Why do they use the term chaotic then? Where is the chaos coming in the binary sequences?

Comment: Well, the sequences are generated by a deterministic process and exhibit no repetiton – if you choose the right starting value $x_1$, e.g., an irrational number (“real number” in my previous comment was not exactly precise) for the tent map. E.g., for $x_1 = π-3$, you will never see any repetion, yet you can exactly predict the sequence.

Comment: But, what is we start with an initial condition and the IC produces chaos and then if we don't see any repetition, then why can't we say the symbolic sequences are chaotic? My understanding is confused. Could you please suggest any article or a book where it may be mentioned

Comment: 1) What do you mean by *IC?* 2) *why can't we say the symbolic sequences are chaotic?* – I did not say that. Classical definitions of chaos (as far as I am aware) simply do not apply here. However, as I tried to elaborate, there are several hallmarks of chaos present in such time series and thus calling them chaotic is to some extent justified. 3) Sorry, I do not know any reference that explicitly discusses this.

Comment: IC = Initial Condition. You mentioned that due to some properties of chaos in these binary / symbolic representation, calling them chaotic to some sense is justified. What would be those properties (hallmarks of chaos) applicable to symbolic dynamics such that they are chaotic (any  links to books or some resource, where for some cases the symbols can be chaotic)? Thank you very much for your continued suggestions and clarification. This is my last Question:

Comment: *What would be those properties (hallmarks of chaos) applicable to symbolic dynamics such that they are chaotic* – I mentioned those already: No regularity, generated by a deterministic process and dependence on initial conditions. Note that the dynamics is value-continuous and time-discrete in this case, not symbolic.